# Filtering objects in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to manage objects in django admin, though I would like to be able only to edit objects with a specific value of some attribute. Precisely I have now in admin.py:

```
class UnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('type', 'name', 'result_file')
    list_filter = ['type']
admin.site.register(Unit, UnitAdmin)
```

And I would like to manage only units with `type='SomeSpecificType'`. I saw something with overriding SimpleListFilter class, though I can't see how this applies here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to override the `get_queryset` in de modelAdmin and filter objects that have `type='SomeSpecificType`.

```
class UnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UnitAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(type='SomeSpecificType')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
class UnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('type', 'name', 'result_file')
    list_filter = ['type']

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and obj.type == 'SomeSpecificType':
            return []
        return ["type", "name", "result_file"]
```